# Current Cygwin version is not supported by Clion, how to install an earlier version of it?

Tags: c++, c, installation, cygwin, clion

I am trying to get my Clion 1.1.1 to work with Cygwin. I've installed Cygwin using its [setup-x86_64.exe](https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe) installer. but when I set Cygwin path in Clion's toolchains dialog, it says:

> Environment: Cygwin; current version is 2.2.1; supported version range is 1.7.32-2.0.x

On the Cygwin website there is a [snapshots page](https://cygwin.com/snapshots/), in which packages are sorted by date (not version) and in [faq page](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.what.version) it says:

> If you are looking for the version number for the whole Cygwin release, there is none. Each package in the Cygwin release has its own version.

So, if there is no version number for whole Cygwin release, what is Clion complaining about?

and if there is, how can I install an earlier version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

afaik, you'll either need an older installer (and some luck on the repos) or someone's older package directory and installer. All recent installers only go back one release which won't be enough to get you back in line with Clion's requirement.

Might also be worth reaching out to Clion and asking them when support for the recent versions is coming out.

Comment: This helped me: [Cygwin time machine project](http://www.fruitbat.org/Cygwin/index.html#cygwintimemachine)